# formula assist sharepoint 2010

Tags: 2010, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

Trying to create column in list settings  using calculated field based on other columns in SharePoint 2010

Using formula :

```
=ROUND((NETWORKDAYS([Actual Start],[Actual End])*8)-IF(WEEKDAY([Actual Start],2)>=6,0,MIN(MAX(24*(MOD([Actual Start],1)-"9:00"),0),8)) - IF(WEEKDAY([Actual End],2)>=6,0,MIN(24*MAX(("17:00"-MOD([Actual End],1)),0),8)),2)
```

Gives me an error.

Formula works in excel!!!

Can anyone assist in having a look at the formula and point if any errors? or correction read.

Basically - Trying to calculate the OFF business hours from a given start and end time

Weekday OFF business hours  (mon -Fri ) 5pm - 9am
Weekend OFF business hours = Friday 5pm to Monday 9AM

Currently below columns exist:

- Actual Start
- Actual End
- Total Duration
- Off business hours  (yet to create) (Total hours - Business hours)

Answer (score 0):

> Formula works in excel!!!

SharePoint is not Excel, many simple Functions are the same,

But complex functions do not exist in SharePoint because there is no concept of a A1:A6 range in SharePoint...
It looks like Microsoft only ported Functions that didn't do anything Excel-ish.. one NETWORKDAYS parameter can be a range.. so they did not port the code.

http://www.viewmaster365.com/365coach/#/Calculated_Column_Functions_List

are tested en tried Functions that do work in SharePoint

Comment: Thanks for info... New to sharepoint and kindly assist in converting above excel formula to sharepoint 2010 format

Comment: well, Microsoft did not convert NETWORKDAYS, so its functionality is not easily replicated. Rough approach would be to substract 2 days for each 7 days